# Javascript Global Variable null

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript like this:

```
var array = new Array();

function initialize()
{
    array.push(1,2,3);
}

alert(array.length);
```

Why is the result is zero (0), it should be three (3).

Comment: Declaring a function doesn't call it. You need to do `initialize()` to actually have the function execute.

Comment: Or use a self-executing function

Answer (score 4):

You have the push code in a function, that needs to be invoked to execute its contents.

In your code you are creating an array and a function which pushes 3 values to that array, but the function is never invoked so the array length will remain zero.

```js
var aray = new Array();

function initialize() {
  aray.push(1, 2, 3);
}

alert(aray.length);
initialize(); // need to call the function to execute its contents
alert(aray.length);
```